# Windows Server 2012 файловый сервер

Tags: windows, сервер, windows-server-2012

Windows Server 2012 данный сервер в рабочей группе, на нем поднята роль файлового сервера.
Создана группа пользователей, которым разрешено работать в файловом сервере, расшаренна папка с файлами.
Вопрос: 
1) Как просмотреть отчет о том, какой пользователь работал с каким файлом(редактировал, или перезаписал файл, а может и удалил)?
2) Если нельзя стандартными средствами ОС посмотреть, может можно написать скрипт на PowerShell?
Сам искал не нашел:)))

Answer (score 1):

Для Ваших целей необходимо настроить аудит файловой системы и уже потом можно смотреть в логах сервера события, которые были произведены над файлами. Или же парсить их с помощью сторонних скриптов. Вот две хорошие (на мой взгляд) статьи о настройке аудита файлов.

https://habrahabr.ru/company/netwrix/blog/208892/

https://habrahabr.ru/post/150149/